# The AppStore doesn't download full pack apps, which were previously bought

Tags: ipad

I bought a new IPad. Started to download all my previous purchased applications, however I get only the basic versions, with an option to pay and unlock the rest of features. HOWEVER, I already purchased the full packs on each application on my previous IPad and paid a lot of money. So how can I get my full pack apps back? It's outrageous if I have to pay all over again for something I already bought.

Answer (score 2):

If you purchased the upgrade inside the app it is called an "in-app purchase". In-app purchases can be restored by tapping on a button inside the apps that says something like "Restore Purchases".